# How to redirect all mitmproxy HTTP traffic to a specific HTTP server?

Tags: networking, proxy, mitmproxy

I want to redirect all HTTP traffic intercepted by `mitmproxy` to a particular HTTP server, regardless of where the HTTP traffic was destined too.

I know how to set an upstream proxy server for `mitmserver`, but in this case I don't want another proxy server, but a (destination) HTTP server instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do exacly? Simply put, looks like you need some DNS and/or ARP spoofing.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be inject a python script that overwrites the destination of every request. You add a `-s script.py` parameter to the mitmproxy/mitmdump command (or call `master.addons.add(script.Script('script.py'))` if you are using mitmproxy library) and add for example the following into your script:

```
from mitmproxy import http

def request(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    flow.request.host = 'google.com'
    flow.request.path = '/'
```

... further customize request method, cookies, etc etc as needed